# Can I find out who recently has been reporting very old addresses to my credit report?

Tags: united-states, credit-report

My credit report at TransUnion includes, in the personal information section, both past addresses and the date each was reported/confirmed to the credit bureau.  Several addresses are reported with dates long after I moved away (in one case, by 9 years! putting it more current than my true current address)

Can I find out what entity has provided this invalid residency information into my report?  What is the process for obtaining such information?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Experian's website](https://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/disputing-an-incorrect-address-on-your-report/), if you want to know more information about a specific address on your credit report, you can

> ... contact Experian following the instructions on your credit report to request more information and determine which creditor reported the address.

I didn't find similar statements online for TransUnion, however, since Experian will tell you who reported it I assume there is no law preventing TransUnion from doing the same. I would contact TransUnion directly to see if they will tell you who reported it. It makes sense that they would tell you because this would enable you to contact that creditor so you can change your address with them, and then they in turn could report the correct address. (Though in this case if the creditor is really old you could also tell them to knock it off.)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times bad data in a credit report is simply a matter of bad transcription at data entry (sloppiness). Send a registered letter to the credit bureau that displays incorrect information, explaining which  information is incorrect, and what the correct information should be. You should probably check what the other credit bureaus have as well and make sure it is corrected.

Comment: The credit bureau's dispute process only allows removing the address completely.  It is a correctly spelled former address.  Since I don't think the "last reported date" is shown to anyone but me, there's nothing to correct.  I do, however, want to find out where the reconfirmations of old addresses are coming from.