# Is it worth fixing a wrong address on my credit report?

Tags: united-states, credit-report

I pulled my credit report today and noticed that one of the former addresses doesn't belong to me. It belongs to my aunt and uncle. I've never lived with them or had mail sent to their house, so aside from sharing a last name I'm not sure why it's showing up on my report. Everything else on the report is accurate.

Last year I noticed the same discrepancy on my report from another reporting bureau and I fixed it. It wasn't difficult to fix, but it was a little time consuming. I'm wondering if it's even worth fixing the incorrect address?

Comment: are you sure your aunt/uncle didn't use your name for something? just something to consider; you know them, we don't.

Comment: I agree, if you are curious, you may want to look at the date of that address history and find out what happened during that time.

Comment: Tangentially related: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/105447/5458  IMO the wrong address on your credit report is only a symptom of the larger problem -- a wrong address on a financial account reporting to the credit bureau.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bureaus make it easy to submit an error correction. It may have no consequence, but given the little effort involved, just do it.

Comment: The other answers did bring up two places where the wrong address could cause small issues: when verifying my identity to the credit bureau and when applying for a loan. Although neither one has been an issue for me (yet), it seems worth the time to correct my report.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a big deal either way. While it won't likely affect your credit score, it could impact those identity verification questions you get sometimes when applying for a credit card online, or electronically signing a document, etc. Sometimes you get a question about "Which of the following is a former address?", so that incorrect address could become a "correct" answer.

If you suspect any chance of identify theft, sure, get it corrected. Me, it's one of those things that I'd never get around to doing, especially if I recognized the address as family.

Comment: That's a great point about the identity verification questions! I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 0):

Not a big deal. When you obtain a mortgage, they may ask for a letter of explanation from you, so you just write a sentence to explain about it.